# Find distinct subset?

Tags: algorithm, math, combinations

All the elements of the set contain only prime number.

Suppose a set  `S = { 3, 3, 5, 7 }`.You have to make subset which contain `highest 3 numbers(May also contain <= set size)` that means subset form `from 0` element `to` highest `3` elements. We count only those subset that contain only unique element.

That is `{ }, { 3 }, { 3 }, { 5 }, { 7 }, { 3, 5 }, { 3, 7 }, { 3, 5 }, { 3, 7 }, { 5, 7 }, { 3, 5, 7 }, { 3, 5, 7 } = 12` subsets. **12 is** our **answer**.

`{ 3, 3, 5 }, { 3, 3, 7 }` **aren't** our **required subset** because they contain duplicate element.

Example 2:
  Set `S = { 2, 3, 5 }` .Suppose you have to make subset highest 2 elements that means `{ }, { 2 }, { 3 }, { 5 }, { 2, 3 }, { 2, 5 }, { 3, 5 } = 7` subsets. **7 is** our **answer**.
`{ 2, 3, 5 }` **isn't** our **required subset** because subset contain **highest 2 elements**.

Is there any mathematical way to solve this problem?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it, including a code attempt. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level. You also need to state exactly what your difficulty is, what you expected from your code, what you got, and any error messages.

Comment: Do you want the number of such sets or do you want the all such set?

Comment: Are you sure that { 3, 5 } and { 3, 7 } should each be counted twice? That implies that the two 3s are considered separate values, which in turn makes a contrast with NOT counting { 3, 3, 5 }.

Comment: @v78 I want number of subset that contain distinct elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is equivalent to finding all of the divisors of some given number `n`. The multiset is the prime factorization of `n` and subsets are divisors.
Limiting the subsets to not have multiples of elements means we are looking only for the divisors which does not have multiples in their prime factorization.

If you had allowed the subsets to include a prime twice, then for `n = p1 ^ k1 * ... * p_t ^ kt` (i.e. the prime `p_i` occur in the set `k_i` times) in a subset every prime has `k_i + 1` options (0 to `k_i` occurences), thus the answer would be `(k1 + 1) * ... * (k_t + 1)` and in your example it would be `(2 + 1) * (1 + 1) * (1 + 1) = 12`

If you disallow a prime to occur twice in the subset, then every prime is either in the subset or it isn't, making the number of possible subsets `2 ^ t`.

In your example, you do not allow a prime to occur twice in a subset, but you do count a subset multiple times, based on the `k_i`'s. For example, you counted `{3,5}` twice as you have 2 times `3` in the original multiset.

You may have notice that the answer in the first method (12) is equivalent to your answer, that's not a coincidence. When you disallow a prime to occur more than once but you do count the same subset multiple times the number of combinations remain the same (even though the subsets are different).

Why is that? 
In every subset each prime `p_i` has again `k_i`options - corresponding to `0-k`: `0` means the prime will not be in the set and `1-k` are the options for **which** occurrence of `p_i` to include in the set. Hence, we have `k_i + 1` for each prime `p_i` as in the first method, and out final formula is `(k_1 + 1) * ... * (k_t + 1)`.

Comment: Let,  
S = { 2, 3, 5 }  
We form subset which contain atmost 2 element.
So, possible subset are { }, { 2 }, { 3 }, { 5 }, { 2, 3 }, { 2, 5 }, { 3 , 5} = 7.
7 is our answer.
But according to your method we get 8. That is wrong.Your method isn't right for this problem!!

Comment: Your method is right for total number of unique subset in a multiset.